# WP: how to add_rewrite_rule() without creating an extra pages

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a serious problem with one of my WP sites.
Plaese take a look at my rewrite rules:

```
function set_rewrite_rules(){
  add_rewrite_tag('%posttype%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]+)[/]([^/]+)[/]page[/]([0-9]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?expertise=$matches[1]&posttype=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]articles[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?article=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]verdicts[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?verdict=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]laws[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?law=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]prosecutions[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?prosecution=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]+)[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?expertise=$matches[1]&posttype=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'set_rewrite_rules');
```

It works great, BUT it creats a lot of extra pages like:

```
/expertise/[EX-NAME]/page/2/page/4/page/3/page/2/page/4/page/2/
```

which normally should return an 404 but for now those pages works & looks like a normal valid page.
Expected result: the pagination should work only with one time matching. for example:

```
/expertise/[EX-NAME]/page/2/
```

Everything works as expected while the `set_rewrite_rules` is commented out.

Comment: Try to add a `$` at the end of first rewrite rule and see what happens.

Comment: @revo tried it. extra pages still available with: `add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]+)[/]([^/]+)[/]page[/]([0-9]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?expertise=$matches[1]&posttype=$matches[2]&paged=‌​$matches[3]', 'top' );`

Comment: What will happen if you remove this specific rewrite rule?

Comment: extra pages still available, but the right pages return an 404 like: `/expertise/[EX-NAME]/page/2/`

Comment: Does *available* mean they lead to a paginated page?

Comment: @revo Yes, as they were before.

Comment: There is only one rewrite rule here that acts on pagination which you removed it already. If pagination works yet (even on those unwanted URL structures) you should look for another rewrite rule somewhere else.

Comment: @revo Thank you. see my answer below.

Comment: Yea, that's why I asked if they lead to a *paginated page* and since you answered *yes* then I didn't see any reason for modifying last rule in the very first place 'cause it doesn't have anything to do with pagination.

Comment: @revo That's exactly why I didn't tried this in the first place... But looks like it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to add $ to the last rule & it looks like no extra pages.

See example:

```
function set_rewrite_rules(){
  add_rewrite_tag('%posttype%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]+)[/]([^/]+)[/]page[/]([0-9]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?expertise=$matches[1]&posttype=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]articles[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?article=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]verdicts[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?verdict=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]laws[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?law=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]*)[/]prosecutions[/]([^/]+)[/]?',
  'index.php?prosecution=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
  add_rewrite_rule( '^expertise[/]([^/]+)[/]([^/]+)[/]?$',
  'index.php?expertise=$matches[1]&posttype=$matches[2]',
  'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'set_rewrite_rules');
```

Thanks @revo for the help!

Comment: If a comment helps to the answer. Ask that user to create an answer so you can reward the point to the correct user. Now you really can't